# Overload operator for different template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading, template-meta-programming

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, std::size_t MaxElements>
struct circular_buffer{};

template <typename circular_buffer>
bool operator==(const circular_buffer &a, const circular_buffer &b) {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    circular_buffer<int, 2> a;
    circular_buffer<int, 3> b;
    a == b;
    return 0;
}
```

This code is work only for 2==3. But my 2 != my 3. Help me to repair operator.

Comment: @NutCracker No, I do not use != neverwhere.

Comment: `circular_buffer` shouldn't be a template parameter to your operator.  That operator is worthless as is. Beyond that, do you understand that by specifying two different sizes you actually have two different end concrete types? One is `circular_buffer<int,2>`, the other is `circular_buffer<int,3>` . They're not the same type. What is it you hope to achieve with your `operator ==` when that happens (or for that matter, in general)?

Comment: @WhozCraig But what parametr must be instead this?

Comment: `template <typename circular_buffer>` name is arbitrary, and currently just hide (for the function) the template class with the same name. So it is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following might work for you:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t M1, std::size_t M2>
bool operator==(circular_buffer<T, M1> const & a, circular_buffer<T, M2> const & b) {
    // some meaningful logic
    return true;
};
```

Problem you have is that `a` and `b` are of different types, i.e. those two objects have different `MaxElements` template parameter. Thus, you need to provide operator `==` overload that will handle this case.